# Android Espresso Test in multi-process app

Tags: android, android-studio, testing, android-testing

I have recorded a Espresso Test and I'm currently trying to run it. The app I'm developing has two processes. The main process is used for background tasks and another process :ui is used for all UI.

This doesn't work well with the instrumentation test runner and I receive the following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Intent in process X resolved to different process X:ui:
```

Is there any way to solve this? Ideally the instrumentation test runner should run in the :ui process.

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting Android 8.0 (API level 26) and higher you can use [Multiprocess Espresso](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/multiprocess.html)